# Not able to divide forloop.counter in django template?

Tags: python, django

I am using django 4.1.5, and i am trying to divide the current forloop counter with 3.
Problem is, i tried so many different syntax, but nothing is working

```
<h3> {{ forloop.counter|div:3 }} </h3>
Exception Value:    
Invalid filter: 'div'

<h3> {{ forloop.counter|div:"3" }} </h3>
Exception Value:    
Invalid filter: 'div'

<h3> {{ forloop.counter//3 }} </h3>
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '//3' from 'forloop.counter//3'

<h3> {{ forloop.counter/3 }} </h3>
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '/3' from 'forloop.counter//3'\
```

how can i get the divided value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for more than 3 hours, from checking the documentation to asking to ChatGPT, nothing really worked, lately  i realised there is no filter for divided. Here is the hack

```
{% widthratio forloop.counter 3 1 %}
```

Reference: https://web.archive.org/web/20160525152906/http://slacy.com/blog/2010/07/using-djangos-widthratio-template-tag-for-multiplication-division/

Comment: this seems too old, i am hoping there is a better way to do that!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the filter is `divisibleby`

```
<h3> {{ forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 }} </h3>
```

Comment: divisibleby:3 would return bool value. I want to have divided value, thanks for the help!